# Allied Telesis AlliedWare gui http server accepted cipher suites

Tags: security, https, ssl

When configuring a [AT-9924T](http://www.alliedtelesis.com/p-1957.html) switch running AlliedWare `2.9.2` to serve ssl encryption on the http server as described in the [manual](http://www.alliedtelesis.com/media/fount/software_reference/291_321/x900/ssl.pdf) like this:

```
create enco key=0 type=rsa length=2048
set system distinguishedname="cn=switch1,o=my_company,c=us"
create pki certificate=cer_name keypair=0 serialnumber=12345 subject="cn=172.30.1.105,o=my_company, c=us"
add pki certificate=cer_name location=cer_name.cer trust=yes
set http server security=on sslkey=0 port=443
```

It only allows two low-security ciphers which are not supported by any modern browsers (firefox,chrome,ie) anymore. The only browser I found which still does support them is IE6, which is not really an option.

```
  Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Accepted  SSLv3  56 bits   DES-CBC-SHA
    Accepted  SSLv3  40 bits   EXP-DES-CBC-SHA
```

How can I configure the http server so it allows better ciphers which are supported by modern browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual you linked to says, in part:

> A 3DES feature licence is required to use 3DES encryption.

So you can pay for this and get 168-bit 3DES. That's probably about all you can do, but it really only would buy you a little time.

With a switch of this age, there probably isn't much else you can do. Keep in mind, also, that there have been many attacks on SSL/TLS in the past few years, and this switch apparently can't be brought up to date for any of them.

If it were me, I'd leave the web interface turned off, and put the switch on my list of things to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The same problem applies to SSH access as well, so just turning the web interface off doesn't really solve the problem. (Even though it probably is easier to make a ssh client to use such a old cipher then it is with a browser..) 
I was just wondering if there was a way without having to pay $$ again, as the switch still regularely receives updates (last on 10-Jul-2013). Maybe someone has a clue :-)

Comment: Funny, they didn't show me any updates. Must be something with their web site. Anyway, I think you're making the argument for replacing the switch for me. :)

Comment: You need to have an account for the "restricted downloads" section to download these updates. As we are pretty happy with these switches and there is no budget for new ones atm, they probably won't get replaced anytime soon. If I could, I would definitely buy some shiny new ones ;-)

Comment: Well, since you seem to have some level of vendor support, you really should be yelling at them very loudly.